# AWS Elasticache CPU usage exceeding 100%

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

We have been using AWS Elasticache for our applications. We had initially set a CPU alarm threshold for 22% (4 core node, so effectively 90% CPU usage), which is based on the recommended thresholds. But we often see the CPU utilization crossing well over 25% to values like 28%, 34%.

What I am trying to understand that how is this theoretically possible, considering Redis is single-threaded ? The only way I can think that this can happen is if there is maintenance operation happening on other cores, which can bump the CPU usage > 25%. Even if the cluster is highly loaded, it should cap CPU usage at 25% and probably start timing out for clients. Can someone help me understand under what scenarios can the CPU usage of a single-threaded Redis instance cross 100% CPU utilization ?

Answer (score 1):

Redis event loop is single-threaded. the Redis process itself is not. There are a couple of extra threads to offline some I/O bound operations. Now, these threads should not consume CPU.

However, Redis also forks child processes to take care of heavy duty operations like AOF rewrite or RDB save. Each forked process generally consumes 100% of a CPU core (except if the operation is slowed down by I/Os), on top of the Redis event loop consumption.

If you find the CPU consumption regularly high, it may be due to a wrong AOF and RDB configuration (i.e. the Redis instance rewrites the AOF or generates a dump too frequently).